# IE7 Shrink-to-fit bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The entire page is an iframe onto another website (in this case, jquery.com just for demo purposes). I have an overlay "Hello World", and if you click on the X it minimizes it (click again it will open it).

It all works fine on IE8, Firefox, Chrome, etc...

However in IE7 it extends the white background to the entire width (see screenshot). I believe it's something to do with the shrink-to-fit or shrink-wrapping.
[image]

Comment: IE Tester is not always consistent/trustworthy. It has plenty of bugs. Use 'real' IE7.

Comment: is there an easy way to have multiple versions of IE running?

Comment: Well, Microsoft provides a solution for this using Virtual PC images. See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with IE8 compatibility mode, if on `div.sidebar` I remove `background-color: #fff`, it's fixed. Removing it makes no visible difference to IE8/Firefox.

To get rid of the page scrollbar on the right in IE7, you need to set `overflow: hidden` on `html` and/or `body`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the use of `width:inherit` on your sidebar that ie7 doesnt like. If you can set a fixed width it should be fine.